# Equivalence relation and its equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $X$ be the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and also that
$$R = \{(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,3),(3,4),(4,4)\}$$

How do I how that $R$ is an equivalence relation; and also its equivalence classes?

I got equivalence class $\{1,2\}$, $\{3,4\}$ but I'm not sure if it's right.

Help appreciated!

Comment: You have to check the three properties explicitly:  reflexive, symmetric, transitive.

Comment: Does $R$ satisfy all three conditions for an equivalence relation as stated on Wikipedia?

Comment: Those can't be the equivalence classes because you have $(1,3)$ in your relation so $1$ and $3$ must be in the same class.

Comment: It looks like this relation is the $\leq$ relation.

Comment: @amWhy Ok, but I never said $\leq$ was an equivalence relation.

Comment: my bad I re-edited the question.

Comment: @computer nerd: please roll back to the previous version. If you want to add a new question, post it separately, or at least add on to the original question, but don't remove the original question, when someone's answered it!

Comment: @Pedro didn't mean to imply that you did...just didn't want to confuse the OP... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Caution***: the originally posted relation is ***not*** an equivalence relation.

Can you show that symmetry fails? For example: $(1, 3) \in R$, but $(3, 1) \notin R$

For your second problem, can you show that it satisfies reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity?